# How to make groovysh use vim as multi-line editor on linux-box

Tags: vim, groovy

rlwrap do gives reliefs for old time editor user.  But it looks not easy to set groovysh use vim/vi as its editor, when working with the interactive console.

As an example, when using "groovysh" on Ubuntu box:

```
groovy:000> set editor=vim
groovy:000> edit
```

Then groovysh get frozen, Ctrl-C is needed to quit.

Comment: If you could tell us what you've tried and what happened that will help us figure it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [Groovy Shell Documentation](http://groovy-lang.org/groovysh.html#GroovyShell-RecognizedPreferences) you can set the `editor` preference to whatever editor you like. So to use vim you would run the command

```
set editor vim
```

to set the variable. If you want this to run every time you start groovy shell (again from  the [documentation](http://groovy-lang.org/groovysh.html#GroovyShell-UserProfileScriptsandState)), you can add that line to the file `~/.groovy/groovysh.profile`

Comment: Use rlwrap can help, the cost is "completion" lost.  They all good tools.